# Mysql stored procedure error -- LOOP and CURSOR

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
DECLARE oldID int;
DECLARE DONE boolean DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE fineCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT `ifLinkID` FROM `image_fine_link` WHERE `image_id` = pimage_id;
DECLARE coarseCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT `icLinkID` FROM `image_coarse_link` WHERE `image_id` = pimage_id;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET DONE = TRUE;


OPEN fineCursor;
OPEN coarseCursor;

read_loop : LOOP
    oldID = NULL;
    FETCH fineCursor INTO oldID;
    IF oldID IS NOT NULL THEN
    CALL update_others(oldID,"delete","fine color",NULL);
    END IF;

    IF !DONE THEN ITERATE read_loop;
    END IF;
    LEAVE read_loop;
END LOOP;

SET DONE = FALSE;

read_lopp : LOOP
    oldID = NULL;
    FETCH coarseCursor INTO oldID;
    IF oldID IS NOT NULL THEN
    CALL update_others(oldID,"delete","coarse color",NULL);
    END IF;

    IF !DONE THEN ITERATE read_loop; 
    END IF;
    LEAVE read_loop;
END LOOP;

CLOSE fineCursor;
CLOSE coarseCursor;
```

And the following error appears, really emergent, any idea ?

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= NULL;
    FETCH fineCursor INTO oldID;
    IF oldID IS NOT NULL THEN
    CALL upd' at line 16
```

Thank you so much sincerely !~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular error is caused by fact that you didn't use [`SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-statement.html) statement to assign a value to a variable.

Change

```
oldID = NULL;
```

to

```
SET oldID = NULL;
```

Comment: @user2741837 You're welcome :) If it was what you were looking for please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.

Comment: Hi indeed there is another problem with this code: the error reports: #1308 - ITERATE with no matching label: read_loop, I guess it's because the scope of label is not visible to the loop, what am I supposed to do instead, as I always need a judgement condition to leave or iterate the loop ? :) Appreciate it if you can help

Comment: You have a typo `read_lopp : LOOP`. `lopp` instead of `loop`. BTW you should use two different labels  e.g. (`read_loop` and `read_loop2`)

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm quite a newbie in stackoverflow. This is the first question I posted :)